# Haskell write your version of a ($) function

Tags: haskell

Could someone help me with writing my own version of the `($)` function? 
This is my attempt which does not work.

```
f function (x:xs) = f (x:xs)
```

Comment: Don't assume the second argument will be a list...

Comment: f function x = f(x) ? Or shall I use foldr somehow?

Comment: Please don't use names like `function` or `list`. Names should describe what something _does_, not what it _is_ (that's what type signatures are for, which you should BTW also always write out). If you can't come up with a proper name, then better call it just `foo` or even `test` or something.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, why do you think you need `:` or `foldr` here? These are exclusive to lists. `$` has nothing to do with lists.

`f function (x) = f (x)` is more like it, however it seems you're confused about whether you defining `function` with `f` as an argument, or vice versa. In fact, `f function (x) = f (x)` means this:

```
f = \function x -> f x
```

i.e. you're defining `f` as a function which takes an argument called `function` (that is never actually used) and another argument `x` to which it then applies the very function you're defining right here... this kind of recursive knot-tying is actually possible in Haskell (and sometimes quite useful), but in this case it doesn't make any sense.

What you actually want to write is much simpler:

```
f $ x = f x
```

note that `$`, because it consists of a non-letter symbol, is an *infix* and therefore parsed differently:

```
($) = \f x -> f x
```

Which means, `$` takes a function and an argument and applies the function to the argument; that's it.

You could also achieve this with a name with letters by using *backticks* to have it parsed as an infix:

```
f `function` x = f x
```

...or simply

```
function f x = f x
```

Comment: And "." function is then function2 f x = f(x) ?

Comment: No. `f(x)` is just a clunky way of writing `f x`, so `function2` is also equivalent to `($)`.

Comment: Should I ask about (.) a separate question :) ?

Comment: Well, preferrably, you should think about it _for yourself_ a bit more. If you get stuck at some particular point, you can then ask about that particular problem.

Comment: I did, but for a beginner this is not easy. I tried several possible ideas but ghci reports problems...

Comment: Well, then wrap up your ideas, how you came by them and how they failed in a question. But make sure you did actually try something that you had good reason to expect it could work.

Answer (score 4):

```
% ghci
GHCi, version 7.10.3: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
Prelude> :i ($)
($) :: (a -> b) -> a -> b       -- Defined in ‘GHC.Base’
infixr 0 $
```

So lets just copy and paste, defining our own `$$` (borrowing the logic from the discussion already presented by @leftaroundabout):

```
($$) :: (a -> b) -> a -> b
f $$ x = f x
infixr 0 $$
```