# Haskell write your version of (.) function

Tags: haskell

Can someone help me with writing my own version of a (.) function in Haskell?
From this post [Haskell write your version of a ($) function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37623871/haskell-write-your-version-of-a-function) I know how to determine a type of this function, but I still have the problem with its body.
I also do not know why ghci refuses to use the name (..).

```
 ($$$) :: (b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c 
 ($$$) f (g x) = ((f g) $) x
 infixr 9 $$$
```

Another idea of mine was for instance this one:

```
($$$) :: (b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c 
($$$) f (g x) = map (f) (g x)
infixr 9 $$$
```

The error message says that "Parse error in pattern: g".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you coming from Lisp? You still seem to assume lists everywhere...

As I already said in the other thread, lists have nothing to do with this task, so neither of `(:)`, `foldr` or `map` can possibly be useful here.

More to the point, the occurence of `(g x)` in the left-hand side of the definition doesn't make sense. (This is not a list, but apparently you think it should be a kind of “argument list”).

As a matter of fact, you *could* define `($$$)` in *un-[curried](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying) form* this way:

```
($$$) :: (b->c) -> (a->b, a) -> c
($$$) f (g, x) = ...
```

...which is exactly the same thing as the more elegant

```
f $$$ (g, x) = ...
```

In this case, you have an argument *tuple* `(g, x)`, which is more or less equivalent to a Lisp list.

In Haskell, we like to write functions curried though. The signature

```
($$$) :: (b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c
```

is in fact parsed as

```
($$$) :: (b -> c) -> ( (a -> b) -> (a -> c) )
```

Hence the way to define such a function is, at the most fundamental level

```
($$$) = \f -> (\g -> (\x -> ... ))
```

Which can be written short as

```
($$$) f g x = ...
```

or

```
(f $$$ g) x = ...
```

In the actual *definition* part, you should similarly get the grasp of how things are actually parsed. As you have by now figured out, the composition operator can be defined as

```
($$$) f g x = f(g(x))
```

In fact, only the outer parentheses are necessary here: the preferred form is

```
($$$) f g x = f (g x)
```

or indeed

```
($$$) f g x = f $ g x
```

If something like `g x` or `(f g)` appears on its own in an expression, it *always* means that the left function is applied to the right argument. For `f g` this doesn't make sense, because though `f` is a function it can not take another function as its argument, only the *result* of such a function. Well, to get such a result you need to apply `g` to an argument!

Answer (score 5):

From the signature:

```
($$$) :: (b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c
```

your function needs 3 arguments. So I would start:

```
($$$) f g x = ...
      | |  \
      | \   a
      |  \
      |   a->b
    b->c
```

**Update**

This attempt at defining `($$$)` does not work:

```
($$$) (f g) x = ...
```

It says that `($$$)` takes *two* arguments. The way I've started to define `($$$)` says that the function takes three arguments.

Comment: I am a real beginner. Could you give me more explanations what I should do? The types are already defined through type definition of ($$$).

Comment: Well, what's the mathematical definition of _(f.g)(x)_ ?   [Wikipedia article on function composition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_composition)

Comment: This does not work either ($$$) (f g) x =  f(y) where y = g(x)

Comment: Answer updated. Just start with what I've written and fill in the `...`

Comment: My last answer was almost correct but for the brackets.

Answer (score 2):

Many thanks for your patience. I used brackets where I should not have. I still have problems with looking at everything (including mathematical operators) as a function. Now the idea of (.) is clear.

```
($$$) :: (b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c 
($$$) f g x =  f(g x)
infixr 9 $$$
```